# Regex to not match if string encountered in middle of pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex which is used to find the region of a file that I need to parse:

```
public static readonly Regex ObjectAction = new Regex($@"(?<Shape>{GetShapeOrRegexSnippet}).+?userdata\s"".*?action=(?<ActionType>\w+)\^(?<ActionPropertyString>.*?)\^\""", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

where `GetShapeOrRegexSnippet` is defined by:

```
private static string GetShapeOrRegexSnippet => ShapeCodes.Aggregate((i, j) => i + '|' + j);
```

That matches a region between (and including) encountering one of the `ShapeCodes` in my collection (`rect`, `circ`, `line` etc) and a line beginning `. userdata`. This works fine for a well formed section such as:

```
line \
    16.5894 34.4828 34.8993 46.3054 19.6616 41.3793 \
    11.6741 44.9507 
. filled 1
. dynprop   \
      (FOX_VAR_3  \
        (= *   \
          (ecolor FOX_VAR_3)))  \
      (o2  \
        (= *   \
          (call fox_oos(__self))))
. userdata "FOX_VAR=3^attr=ECOLOR^attrval=3^required=0^var=UPDATETAG33^delta=1.000000^conv=LOOKUP^type=LONG^minstate=0^num_entries=2^entries=7,7^END_FOXV=  ^oos_obj=0002"
```

However, it is entirely possible that a given shape might not have an associated `userdata` string, so is it possible to stipulate that if the `Regex` encounters any of the `ShapeCodes` again before it encounters a `userdata` string it will not match that section and will continue to check the else of the file?

My initial thoughts were to use a negative lookahead, but this doesn't work (I'm quite new to `Regex` so I could be doing something wrong though):

```
(?<Shape>rect|frect|fpie|spline|poly|line|fsec|fcir).+?(?!rect|frect|fpie|spline|poly|line|fsec|fcir)userdata\s\".*?attr=(?<AttributeType>\w+)\^(?<AttributePropertyString>.*?)\^(?=(?:END_FOXV))
```

Is this possible? If so, could you please point me in the right direction, if not, could you please let me know and I'll try a different approach.

Comment: Replace the first `.+?` with `(?:(?!{GetShapeOrRegexSnippet}|action=).)*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this seems to do the trick, thankyou! If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that `.+?` matches any 1+ chars as few as possible, *but* from the first match of `{GetShapeOrRegexSnippet}`. That is why it may match across several blocks.

Replace the first `.+?` with `(?:(?!{GetShapeOrRegexSnippet}|action=).)*`, a tempered greedy token, that will only match 0+ chars that do not start the sequence matched with `{GetShapeOrRegexSnippet}` or  `action=`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but couldn't you just wrap the entire section (I guess it's the `userdata` block) in parens and put a `?` after it?  That would match zero or one instances of that block.  Something like this (just showing the `userdata` block of the regex):

```
(?:userdata\s"".*?action=(?<ActionType>\w+)\^(?<ActionPropertyString>.*?)\^\"")?
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, as I only want it to match if there is a userdata string before the next symbol's section starts so basically:

rect /
.....
.....
. userdata ... 

would match, but:

line /
....
....
rect

would not match, and the search would continue from `rect`. There are several of these blocks in every search.